# How can I get the id of the logged in user

Tags: c#, linq, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a request form where I would like to take the id of the user in session `IdEmpLogin`, In case I need to know who made the request

this the models y using

```
 public class NewRequestViewModel
{
    public int IdEmpLogin { get; set; }
    public int IdEmpTarget{ get; set; }
    public IDictionary<int, string> TargetUser{ get; set; }
    public int EmpTargetCarId{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime RequestDate{ get; set; }
    public int Status{ get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public <System.DateTime> ResponseDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my login, for the login I am using the `domain model`

```
public ActionResult Login(String User, String Pass)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new sir_cjfEntities())
            {
                var usr =(from d in db.employees
                          where d.user==User && d.password== Pass && d.status== true
                          select d).FirstOrDefault();
                if (usr == null)
                {
                    return Content("The username or password is incorrect");
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["user"] = usr;
                    return Content("1");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("Error" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

`Domain Model`

```
public partial class employees
{
    public employees()
    {
        this.cars= new HashSet<cars>();
        this.parking= new HashSet<parking>();
        this.request= new HashSet<request>();
        this.request2= new HashSet<request>();
    }

    public int id_employee{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string lname{ get; set; }
    public string user{ get; set; }
    public string password{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> status{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<cars> cars{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<parking> parking{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<request> request{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<request> request{ get; set; }
}
```

how can i get the id of the logged in employee and save it in my request table?

```
public ActionResult NewReq()
    {
        var model = new NewRequestViewModel
        {
            TargetUser= new Dictionary<int, string>()
        };
        using (var db = new sir_cjfEntities())
        {
            model.TargetUser= db.employees.ToDictionary(x => x.id_employee, x => x.name+ " " + x.lname);
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewReq(NewRequestViewModel model)
    {
        var db = new parkingDBEntities();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.TargetUser= db.employees.ToDictionary(x => x.id_employee, x => x.name+ " " + x.lname);
            return View(model);
        }
        var req= new request();
        using (db)
        {
            model.RequestDate= DateTime.Now;
            model.TargetUser= db.employees.ToDictionary(x => x.id_employee, x => x.name+ " " + x.lname);
            req.status= null;
            req.id_emp_logged = model.IdEmpLogin;//get logged in user id
            req.id_emp_target = model.IdEmpTarget;//target user
            req.emp_tar_car_id= model.EmpTargetCarId; //I have to get the car registered by the target user
            req.request_date= model.RequestDate;
            db.request.Add(req);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Redirect(Url.Content("~/CRequest/"));
    }
```

As you can see, I'm currently manually entering the id

and this is the view

```html
@model ParkingRequest.Models.ViewModels.NewRequestViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New Request";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("NewReq", "CRequest", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Error", new { @class = "text-danger", @type = "text" })

            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdEmpLogin)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.IdEmpLogin, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("IdEmpLogin", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.IdEmpTarget)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.IdEmpTarget, new SelectList(Model.TargetUser, "Key", "Value"),
          new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("IdEmpTarget", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.EmpTargetCarId)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.EmpTargetCarId, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessage("EmpTargetCarId", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:right;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Apply for" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The current user is stored in the HttpContext.User property after authentication. The `Login` method is seriously broken though and has to be discarded. Passwords should never be stored in a database. They should be salted, hashed at least 1000 times with a strong cryptographic hash algorithm *meant for passwords* and only the final hash should be stored. ASP.NET already offers secure database storage, simply by checking the `individual accounts` option in the `Authentication` settings

Comment: Check [Create a secure ASP.NET MVC 5 web app with log in, email confirmation and password reset (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset#hook-up-sendgrid) in the [Security,Authentication and Authorization section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/)docs. It shows how to easily store passwords securely and use email for confirmation and password requests.

Comment: Other articles in the same section show how to add Facebook, Google or Twitter authentication to your app. ASP.NET Core offers the same mechanisms, even from the command-line

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos About the login, this is just a test project, the one I'm using to work has already encrypted the passwords, but thanks for the observation.

Comment: So what's the question, what's the relevant code? If you used `Individual Accounts` you'd be able to get the user through the HttpContext. None of the code snippets is trying to retrieve the user account. There's an **insecure** attempt to save the user name instead of a token in the session but no session cookie is set. Session state is stored in cookies, which means a malicious client could easily replace the user account with another one. Authentication cookies on the other hand are encrypted and validated

Comment: Before trying to roll your own authentication you need to understand the built-in mechanisms, how they work and *why*. The built-in mechanisms offer extensive customisations, so you don't need to create your own authentication to customise the login pages, user profiles or 2FA.

Comment: You can just check the code of the built-in implementations too. In some ASP.NET MVC versions all the relevant pages were added to the project. You could just read the default `Login` controller to see how it worked, how it set cookies etc. In later versions those several dozens of pages came pre-built into a DLL, but you can still get the source pages through [ASP.NET Identity Scaffolding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)